# Git- Deleted files getting in the way of merge?

Tags: git

I have a merge conflict that I'm not sure how to handle, here is the scenario.

I have **Alpha** and **Gamma**.

Alpha looks like this because Thing.js was deleted

```
Folder
|___Thing.html
|___Thing.css
```

And beta looks like this

Gamma looks like this because Thing.html and Thing.css were deleted

```
Folder
    |___Thing.js
```

I'd imagine that merging them into Gamma would give me this:

```
Folder
    |___Thing.html
    |___Thing.css
    |___Thing.js
```

Instead it appears to delete Thing.js and update Thing.html and Thing.css.

I've been googling for half an hour trying to get a concise reason as to why this happens and how to fix it and I'm coming up on empty. Has anyone had a similar experience and if so how'd you fix it? And why does it happen?

Comment: They are really close but gamma was updated the most recently. They are apart by like an hour or so

Comment: You mentioned in the question that you have a merge conflict. When you run git merge alpha from gamma, does it prompt you to deal with conflicts?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know what to do to get the files I want. Or what process I need to follow.

Comment: You can manually select the information from the branch you care about by deleting the appropriate section here's a tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/deal-merge-conflicts-git/ That will allow you to get the result you're after. As to why this happens, you can read on the git documentation about merges here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge What happens is your commits from Alpha are added to branch Gamma. If you delete the html and css in Gamma, then merge Alpha into Gamma, then the commit where you made your changes occurs after your deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're imagining that:

```
git merge blah
```

looks at `blah` in comparison to `HEAD` / the current branch.

It doesn't.

What `git merge` does—at least for the normal cases of merges—is to find the *merge base* between the current branch, i.e., `HEAD`, and the commit specified by `blah`:

```
             C--D--E   <-- curbranch (HEAD)
            /
...--o--o--B
            \
             F--G--H--I   <-- blah
```

The merge base is, roughly, where the two branches come together as we go back through history.

Each of the uppercase letters above represents a commit (a thing with a big ugly hash ID, that saves a source snapshot).  Git now does, in effect:

```
git diff --find-renames B E   # what we did
git diff --find-renames B I   # what they did
```

These are *changes* (or change-sets).  The first shows what we did, starting from commit `B` which we shared with them, skipping right over all the middle steps, to see how it looks in the end.

The second shows what *they* did, starting from *the same* starting point.  As with our branch, Git skips over all the intermediate commits; only the final result is "interesting".

Git then *combines* the two sets of changes.  If we deleted two files, and they deleted one of those two files plus a third file, the combined result is "delete all three files".

If you don't want the files deleted after all, you may run:

```
git merge --no-commit
```

to avoid committing the final result.  You can then `git checkout` specific files from commit `B` (you will need to locate it yourself for this particular case):

```
git checkout <hash-of-B> <path>
```

and when you have the source arranged the way you want the merge result to look, run `git commit`.  Beware, though: this creates what people call an *evil merge*.  That is, it's a merge result that is not the same as the inputs to the merge.

Another alternative is to create at least one new commit (added to `curbranch` or `blah`, or even on a new branch) that *puts back* the files that should be put back, in preparation for the merge.  If *both* branch tips have deleted a file that should be retained, you'll need to do this with both branches (or two new branches).

You can now merge the new commit with the other commit or the other new merge commit, using the same merge base `B`.  Now the two inputs do not delete the file, so the merge result will have the file.

Answer (score 1):

A hack is to do the merge *how ever* to get on top of the branch. Then get the files you want from a previous commit. Copy / modify / delete the files to get the situation you would like to have (add if necessary) and commit again.

Why is the behaviour as it is?

The .js file got deleted in Alpha and was not modified in a later commit so it ought to be deleted.
The other two files were deleted in beta. You wrote, they were **updates** in gamma? I assume a modification parallel to beta resulting in a merge conflict (maybe a newline in alpha?). Because of two parallel and incompatible modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you imagine gamma would look a certain way, because you think of a merge as combining content.  This is not true, though.  A merge combines changes.

Deleting a file is a change.  On a branch, if you delete a file and commit that change, you are saying to git "to implement the feature for which this branch was created, I need to delete this file".  It's almost always the case that the "other side" into which you will merge this didn't *also* delete the file; so for your case to be handled the way you envision, would mean almost every attempt to delete a file would be undone at the next merge.  Most users would find that rather upsetting.

So instead, you do the merge and git says "well, on this side to get the job done thing.js had to be deleted; but on this side to get the job done thing.js had to be modified.  I am not going to guess how to sort that out, so the user doing the merge must tell me."  That's a conflict.

More and more I see workflows where people want to make a branch and then delete from that branch all the files they don't plan to work on in that branch.  The above is why those workflows are 100% wrong.  If you must have sparse work trees, you can use sparse checkout; but if you commit deletion of the files then you're going to get unwanted results in the merge.

In the case where the "other side" of the merge modified the file, you're relatively lucky because you will get a conflict and you can resolve the conflict by taking the version from the branch that didn't delete the file.  If there were no conflict, the file would be deleted silently.